# Sending multiple mail in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mandrill

A web app I'm building will send out invoices to clients every third month. This will be a scheduled event that is run in the middle of the night, but under development I have put this code into a route so I can test it.

In short i want the code to do the following.

1. QUery all unsent invoices from DB.
2. Make a call to Mandrill for each invoice (In this call I'm also invoking a function creating a Mandrill message object from the invoice).
3. For every message Mandrill send, Update the DB invoice `sent: true`.
4. When all invoices are sent, make a final callback in the `async.waterfall`

The code below works. but i have some concerns regarding the `_.each`.

```
invoices.post('/invoices/send/', function(req, res, next) {

    async.waterfall([
        // Query all unsent invoices
        function(callback) {
            db.invoices.find({sent: false}).toArray(callback);
        },

        // Send all unsent invoices
        function(invoices, callback) {
            if (invoices.length === 0) {
                var err = new Error('There are no unsent invoices');
                err.status = 400;
                return next(err); //Quick escape if there are no matching invoice to process
            }

            // Make a call to Mandrill transactional email service for every invoice. 
            _.each(invoices, function(invoice) {
                mandrillClient.messages.sendTemplate({template_name: "planpal-invoice", template_content: null, message: mandrillClient.createInvoiceMessage(invoice)}, function(sendResult) {
                    console.log(sendResult);
                    db.invoices.updateById(invoice._id, {$set: {sent: true}}, function(err, saveResult) {
                        console.log(saveResult);
                    });
                }, function(err) {
                    return next(err);
                });
            });

            callback(null, 'done');
        }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

I'm thinking I should use `async.eachLimit` instead.... but I dont know how to write it. 
I have no idea what i should set the limit to, <strike>but I guess several parallel request would be better than running all mandrill request in serie like above, am I wrong?</strike> **EDIT** `_.each` run the callbacks in parallel. The difference from a `async.each` is that I dont get a "final callback"

**Conclusion:** Should i use a `async.eachLimit` above? If Yes, what is a good limit value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the https://github.com/caolan/async#each function.

it will execute the queries in parallel too

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking there is a good reason for a limit when sending request to a Mail service. So my app wont drown the server in request and get blocked/ignored or similar. But I really dont know if this is neccesary... Do you? :)

Comment: FWIW the Mandrill API docs don't specifically mention rate limit errors, but there is [this information](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/22011078-Quota-and-Reputation-System) on how their hourly sending quotas work. So I would guess you should be fine with just using `each()`.